# How to get the full text in Tweepy v2 search

Tags: twitter, tweepy, truncated

I'm trying yo get the full text in twitter search using Tweepy v2. I used `search_recent_tweets()`, but it returns only truncated tweets.

```
import tweepy
import credentials

client = tweepy.Client(credentials.bearer_token)

query = 'policy'

response = client.search_recent_tweets(query, tweet_fields = ["created_at", "text", "source"], max_results=10)

tweets = response.data
tweets[0]['text']
```

The output is:

> "RT @saletan: I wasn't aware of this policy till it happened to my
> son. I told the story below.\n\nSix weeks after they locked his
> account, he…"

Comment: You can use `tweet_mode='extended'` and `full_text` attribute

Comment: In the documentacion `search_recent_tweets()` don't have the attribute tweet_mode.

Comment: This is because the Tweet is a retweet, so you need to use `expansions` to retrieve the original Tweet in an `includes` object and that should have the full Text. There is no such thing as extended Tweet mode in API v2.